# Vagrant installation issue

Tags: drupal, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am trying to install vagrant for my Drupal sites on Windows 10 machine. But I am getting below error. Kindly suggest
Vagrant version:  2.2.14
Oracle VM version: 6.1
vagrant-hostsupdater (1.2.1, global)
vagrant-vbguest (0.29.0, global)
vagrant-winnfsd (1.4.0, global)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused due to Anti Virus Software(Sentinel). By uninstalling it I could fix this issue.